# Alternative word for "human rights" but across multiple races (including demi-humans)

Tags: society, fantasy-races

What would be best "human rights" word equivalent for all intelligent beings, including humans, demi-humans, and other intelligent life forms?

Example of demi-humans are Lizard folk, Cat people, etc.

Intelligent meaning they can read & write and understand law.

Comment: Sophont: An intelligent being; a being with a base reasoning capacity roughly equivalent to or greater than that of a human being.

Comment: I apologize, but even though this was a wildly popular question, it's been proposed that "[what should I name X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6259)" questions and [technobabble](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6516) are off-topic for this site.  So, to disuade future OPs, I'm voting to close as too broad (or POB, take your pick).  People who disagree are welcome to bring the issue up in Meta (I encourage it).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Pratchett has covered this

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120976/is-there-a-term-used-to-define-all-sentient-races

Comment: Realcase. In my current book-in-the-works (a sci-fi title), I'm using the word _metasapient_ to refer to the various races, including spirits, AI and intelligent animals. The "human rights" equivalent is encoded and referred as _Universal Rights Manifesto_.

Comment: Relevant quote from Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country. ["**Human** rights", the very name is racist...](https://youtu.be/t2TDf9XU09k?t=114)

Comment: Unless they can freely interbreed, saying "races" is wrong. That's different species.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Natural rights

The concept of [natural law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_law) appeared first in Ancient Greek philosophy. It was championed by the Roman Cicero and expanded into great treatises by Averroes and Thomas Aquinas.

Natural law asserts that certain rights are inherent by virtue of the nature of the world. While the Abrahamic religions obviously centered their view of natural law on *human rights* extended by *God*; it is easy to transfer this concept to the *rights of all intelligent races* extended by *Nature* (or God, if your setting has an omnipotent [Demiurge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demiurge)).

The rights conferred onto all intelligent peoples by natural law are naturally (heh!) referred to as 'natural rights'.

Comment: This is what I came here to say as well.  There's a [short (~10 min) video on the history of human rights](https://www.humanrights.com/) that traces this back in simplistic form.  Natural law -> natural rights -> human rights.  You only have to go one step back in the linguistic evolution for a phrase that could apply to aliens just as well.  :)

Answer (score 51):

Denizen rights, Person rights, Personal rights, Individual rights, life rights, citizen rights.

Perhaps the most similar is *Person rights* because in some fields like anthropology the word *person* is used as distinct from *human* to mean a thinking being whose interests need to be taken into account (which includes humans, of course, but also might include spirits, animals, or even plants, objects and physical phenomena).

Of course, Human rights are called Human rights for a range of historical and accidental reasons, not exactly that people sat down and came up with the best term that they could. There could be a particular historical (in your world) reason why the name of a movement for certain groups of rights would have a particular name. They could be called *Delhi Rights* because the first international treaty on them was signed in Delhi. They could be called *international rights* or *transcendent rights*, or *global rights* because of the desire for them to operate in all places for all people. They could be called *Universal rights*, they could be called *all rights*. They could be named after a person, country, or region where they were argued for first (or loudest). Or they could be named for the way they were formulated: *declared rights*, or *formal rights*, or *enumerated rights*, or *agreed rights*.

If you want to get away from the individualist framework of contemporary western human rights discourse, you could call them *community rights* or *collective rights*. You could also phrase (and frame) them as 'freedoms' or 'expectations' or 'safeties' or 'standards' rather than 'rights'. The sky is the limit!

Comment: +1 Denizen is my go to. Its different enough that we don't associate it with people or humans. The other ones make sense, but since we use it in society, it has a more humanly feel to it.

Comment: "Person rights" is fitting in English, but if you are hoping to have your work translated to other languages there could be issues. Some languages don't make a distinction between "person" and "human". Japanese is one such language, I think. They use "ningen" for both. It feels a bit "dehumanizing" (wordplay intended) when you read a translated manga and a character says something like "She's a good person... I mean 'elf'".

Comment: @Kapten-N definitely would pose a dilemma for any translator! I think that the regular phrase 'human rights' is sometimes variously translated as "rights of people" or "rights of man" with man as either singular or plural... definitely other languages will have different considerations

Comment: perhaps add "sentient rights" in that list so I don't have to waste space with that as an answer if it can be added to this list.

Comment: "denizen" would apply to any living creatures, such as flies, perhaps down to bacteria.  Most cultures would not assign the same level of rights to these as they would to sentient beings.

Comment: @MaxWilliams In our world, yes. But I can imagine stretching Denizen from "all those who dwell here" to "all those who *dwell* here" where *dwell* is interpreted along some kind of demi-human consciousness level class. For a fantasy world, I think it's reasonable

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata I guess that if it's capitalized then it makes it clearer that it has some special meaning beyond the dictionary definition.

Comment: `Human rights are called Human rights for a range of historical and accidental reasons` The main reason is an absence of any non-humans having needed to be included. It's the same reason why we still talk about "the sun" and "the moon". We don't have a second one so there was never a need to distinguish between two suns or two moons. If Earth had two moons, we would refer to them by a unique name.

Comment: Without diluting the comment, the Sun and moon do in fact have their own names, Sol and Luna. Hence the terms Solar and Lunar. They're just more specific and not quite as pervasive in our culture. I'd bet once we have a colony amongst the moons of Jupiter, they won't be calling Earth's moon "The Moon"

Comment: Can't wait for interstellar linguist debates over the term "solar energy".

Comment: @Flater if non-human didn't need to be included and it was obvious that this was the case, wouldn't they just be called "The Rights" rather than "Human rights?"

Comment: Also, the origin of the term "human rights" is from translating documents from the French Revolution which was changed from Man to Human to be gender neutral in english, and I'm no historian but I would be willing to wager that the French terminology is related to the anti-catholic sentiments of the revolution. My guess is that the concept of inherent rights of 'man' was to ground morals in a secular context. I only mean to show that the choice of term "Human Rights" can be viewed as a historical semi accident rather than result of a conscious process to select the most appropriate term

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata: It's still "the _moon_", not "the satellite". The moon is a satellite, but it would be ambiguous with manmade satellites. Distinctions are made up to a point where they are sufficient. "the moon" is sufficient, but "the rights" would not be sufficiently distinct. There are still other rights that e.g. a nation can grant its citizens, which _for those citizens_ would also be "the rights that apply to us" but not "the rights that apply to all humans". To denote the latter, "human rights" is the needed level of distinction.

Comment: Citizens of the empire :D

Comment: @Ruadhan: They don't really have their own names. "Sol" and "luna" are merely "sun" and "moon" in Latin, respectively. Hence why any star can have a "solar system", and any planets moon can have a "lunar eclipse" of its respective planet and star(s).

Comment: "global rights" is biased against beings that don't live on planets.

Comment: @Kapten-N Just to add another example: in Dragon Ball Super, Zamasu uses the word "ningen" to refer to both humans and alien races. It seems that he uses it as a slur as he's a god who sees mortals as inferior beings, but he might be using the word correctly. This may not be the best example, but even in Japanese Language Stack Exchange [they have discussed](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38481) about these particular uses of "ningen".

Comment: @Sharur Given those names were invented when the sky consisted of the Sun, Moon and Stars, I suspect coming up with specific names is going to be necessary at some point. We're already more or less there, the moons of other planets have specific names, and ours is just "The Moon". The Ur-Example if you like. But that's more a frame-of-reference thing, we only have one moon that we see on a regular basis. When we have children growing up on other planets and have to explain this; distinguishing the moon over their heads from the moon around Earth is going to get really clumsy without a name.

Answer (score 31):

Sentient rights, sapient rights, legal resident rights, citizen rights...

There are basically two things you need to consider here.

First, **there is no single correct option**. This is because these "fundamental rights" (another option) are not actually "fundamental" rights, they are legal constructs granted by a political process. The correct word to use is the one that properly describes that political process and the reasoning behind it. So to pick the right word you need to make up the history behind how people got those right and why and then (sorry about this) briefly try to think like a politician selling the idea.

Sometimes, surprisingly often really, the terms that stick were originally coined by people opposing the idea as derogatory terms. This is even more likely if the lofty ideas have a history of implementation problems. So you might want to think about it from that direction as well.

Second, The legal rights are not a single monolithic object. For example, while there is almost infinite number of possible terms you could choose, the reason I picked the four in the beginning (sentient rights, sapient rights, legal resident rights, citizen rights) is that they represent a continuous scale of scope. There are sentients that are also sapient and have sapient rights in addition to their sentient rights, but all sapient beings are also sentient and automatically have all the sentient rights in addition to their sapient rights. And so on. So you would want multiple different grades of rights with separate names and legal and ideological basis.

Historically and realistically in addition to such logical and neatly scoped rights you would also have a patchwork of more speficic rights and privileges granted in a specific historical context without any overlying design and logic. Say a specific group of refugees or immigrants or a religious or ethnic minority might get a special deal in response to a political crisis and that deal will then be on the books for decades or even centuries. You might want to add one or two such special cases to your system to make it look more realistic. Sadly, messy -> realism.

Comment: I would pick "sapient rights" over "sentient rights", because sentience includes animals that are commonly not considered intelligent the same way as humans are intelligent. A sentient being is aware of its surroundings and is capable of making decisions. A sapient being is able to reason about the future and communicate that reasoning with some kind of language.
Sentient rights would be an extension of animal rights and sapient rights would be an extension of human rights. This would also include different levels of true AI.

Comment: @Kapten-N I wanted to emphasize the way rights and the groups they apply to form hierarchies. And the way different societies would choose different rationals for fundamental rights. **You** would pick "sapient rights", but to a society with different world view "sentience" would be the main dividing line. You can actually see signs of this with some animal rights movements.

Comment: “Inalienable rights” would also fit with this answer as a term reflecting the politics leading to those rights.

Comment: @VilleNiemi: _"but to a society with different world view "sentience" would be the main dividing line"_ Sure, but then you're redefining sentience from how an English speaker now understands it. A cat is sentient, as is a housefly. But OP's  focus ("they can read & write and understand law") is much more narrow than sentience ("cat people" is not the same as "cats"). "Sapient" is much closer to OP's focus, as per the real world definition of "sapient". Note that the dictionary definition of "sapient" refers to humans as we do not have any other sapient species in real life at the moment.

Comment: @SRM: "Inalienable" doesn't actually describe the target audience but rather the permanent nature of the rights. We often describe human rights as inalienable, but that doesn't mean "inalienable" inherently means "human" (or human-like in OP's case)

Comment: The words "inalienable human rights" were written down by people who fundamentally believed the rights didn't come from politics but pre-existed and the rulers had an obligation to respect them.

Comment: @Flater I am not redefining "sentience". I specifically and intentionally included a wider category than the specific question requires or people commonly consider for wider context. Since it seems to confuse people that might have been a mistake? Fun fact, I actually checked the text book definition of "sentience" **before** writing the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Universal rights.

This is a term in use on earth today for just the rights you are referring to. It means the rights are universal and apply to all. Yet it is implied that they do not apply to animals.

It could perhaps also be interpreted as rights that apply in the universe.

If the rights originated with one race, it may be named after them, or other historical reasons. So Human rights could also be a valid name.

Comment: This was going to be my answer, since *Universal* Declaration of Human Rights.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't only apply to sentient races.

Comment: @vsz the way it is currently used on Earth it does only apply to sentient races, even though the name could imply it applied to dogs, computers and cars. Not all names make sense the way "Human rights" does.

Comment: @AmiralPatate: In the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, the **declaration** is universal (i.e. not bound to a particular region). That has nothing to do with who the rights apply to, which is described by "Human".

Comment: @Osthekake: The UDHR does **not** apply to all sentient races. Animals are sentient, but the UDHR does not apply to them. [Several examples](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/): (1) No one shall be held in slavery or servitude (2) the right to recognition everywhere as a person before the law (3) the right to a nationality (4)  the right to own property (5)  the right to take part in the government of his country; and so on... **All human(like)s are sentient creatures, but not all sentient creatures are human(like).**

Comment: @Flater I never meant to say that it does apply to all sentient beings. Only that the name is different from the application.

Comment: @Osthekake: "Universal Rights" is not used on Earth today. At least no by itself; it's a shortening of the full name: "Universal Declaration of **Human Rights**". The rights are labeled as human, and are applied to humans. The application is the same as the name. OP could use "universal rights" by itself in their own story regardless of it being used in real life, but your assertion that "universal rights" is currently used in reality is not correct.

Comment: @Flater While it's difficult to prove that a phrase is used in reality or not, I feel that it would be correct to say that it is used even if it was just a shortening. The declaration is different from the rights themselves, however. On google I found the Universal Rights Group, which I would say is usage, though you could argue they mean something else by these words. Still, I'm convinced that most people would know what is meant by "universal rights". I will leave it as is.

Comment: @Flater If tomorrow we find the lost city of Atlantis inhabited by mermaids, we either nuke them to hell or we'll have to apply the UDHR to them, making it a Universal Declaration of Rights. And then when Atlantis wants to chastise China like the rest of the world when we don't have planes to sell, they can't invoke their human rights record since that would exclude their species, they can't invoke their rights record that just sounds silly. So what perfectly encompassing word could you use? Three guesses, and it's neither _declaration_ nor _of_.

Comment: @AmiralPatate: Your argument makes no sense. You cannot hold whoever decided on the UDHR name responsible for not accounting for a sapient species that was not known to exist at the time of naming the UDHR. The assumption that something decided in the past must account for all future possibilities is nonsensical. Upon discovery of these mermaids, we will need to evaluate their sapience and reconsider the name/applicability of things that may be called something else (human, no modifier, ...) but in reality refers to all sapients.

Comment: @AmiralPatate: Similarly, when Earth somehow gets a second moon (visible to the human eye and actually talked about by humans), we will have to re-evaluate calling the original moon "the moon" and instead will have to start using a name that clearly distinguishes them ("Luna" vs "WhateverTheNameOfTheNewMoonIs"). You can't just argue that because we've been calling it "the moon" so far, that we thus cannot allow a second moon to come into the picture, nor can you conclusively argue that existing documentation regarding "the moon" clearly does or doesn't extend to the second moon.

Answer (score 13):

**Sophont rights** is another option.

This one has the advantage of being well known in the SF genre already. According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophont): *(chiefly science fiction) An intelligent being; a being with a base reasoning capacity roughly equivalent to or greater than that of a human being. The word does not apply to machines unless they have true artificial intelligence, rather than mere processing capacity.*

[Sophont Rights](https://eldraeverse.com/2011/04/27/sophont-rights/) (in the Eldraeverse)

[Universal Declaration of Sophont Rights](https://orionsarm.com/eg-article/485acb81cdb0b)

[Guarantees of Sophont Rights](http://members.tripod.com/~starbase_10/rights.htm)

[Pulsar Strike](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12409812/1/Pulsar-Strike) by Cyrus Bortel

[Traveller News Service](https://calormen.com/tns/mt.html)

Comment: This answer could be improved with a definition of Sophont, as it's an uncommon word.

Comment: Hmm, I have not come across any of those sources, would have to guess at meaning from context.  Also I wonder if anyone has seen a translated copy and how the term was butchered?

Comment: @KalleMP "Sophont"? It was created by a science fiction writer.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181787/where-did-the-term-sophont-originate/181788

Comment: @KalleMP -- I definitely recommend the Eldraeverse books! Very creative mind wrote those. Of course, this is not intended to be (nor ought we expect it to be) an exhaustive concordance of every use of "sophont" in existence. There are probably sources you've come across. There are also squillions of uses in more ephemeral resources like SF, fan and writer forums. It's a well known word, especially among SF readers, writers and dabblers.

Comment: @Josh -- definition & link added!

Comment: Sophon is also commonly used in the Schlock Mercenary webcomic (not sure if applied to AI but still)

Answer (score 12):

Wouldn't a world with multiple sentient species have a simple term for all of them, something a bouncer in a bar could apply and not just a philosopher? Introduce that word early on in your story or game.

You define intelligent as being able to read and write and to follow the law. Does that mean stereotypical orcs are outlaws in civilized lands?

- *Citizen's rights* is not quite right because they would cover non-citizen foreigners. You'd have to find a new word for citizenship-derived rights.
- *Civil rights* are somewhat distinct from *human rights* in our world, but the word is recognizable to readers.
- If you use *people's rights* you define only those law-abiding races as people. That might be desirable in your setting.
- Perhaps use "folk" as a shorthand for "civilized folks" and thus *folk rights*.

Answer (score 8):

How about ***inalienable rights***? When we talk about human rights, we're usually talking about the basic minimum of rights that most people agree that everyone should have. These rights are essential and cannot be taken away - everyone deserves them simply by being.

This could also be a bit of an ironic descriptor in a sci-fi story (inalienable rights for aliens).

Answer (score 5):

As you bring up the law aspect, I think for simplicity and to make the distinction clear to the beings and to your readers I would stick to something like **Statutory Protected Rights** to indicate that it is whatever you decide that is bound by the law.  True rights I personally believe should cover more but will not be protected because the aggrieved parties will not have the legal skills or standing.

In story you could have some small side mention by way of a character relying on or bumping into them illustrate the scope and depth of the rights.

Sort of like:
"Jonestar was still detoxing from the night before and and could not help being irritated by the early morning activities of the Treblim.  Every night they would rebuild their grass and reed temple encroaching on the pedestrian way outside their dwelling next door and hold worship.  The sweeper robot would just wait for almost an hour with the plasma torches hissing on idle and prevent his sleep and only after the last Trebler bowed his way out and removed the sign of the n-Th dimension could the sweeper knock the encroaching part of the structure down and sanitise the walk way.  Jonestar was generally a tolerant Felling but a hungover cat needs to sleep.  It was times like this that the whole business of the **Statutory Protected Rights** extending to all sorts of snack food was hard to stomach."

Hmm, perhaps I should try my tentacles at writing SciFi, it might even be fun.

Answer (score 4):

You could say "**soul rights**".

In nautical and aeronautical contexts "souls on board" is used to indicate the number of people on board, irrespective of whether they are men, women or children, or crew or passengers.

Comment: This would be too broad for most sapients to condone as it gives their food too many rights to fight back.  It would suit me as I am a vegetarian.

Comment: @KalleMP Strictly speaking, the term "souls on board" excludes animals when talking about ships or planes. I suppose it depends on the details of OP's world, whether he considers "cat people" more cat or more people.

Comment: Sure, there are three aspects, what is convention, what is current understanding by those in power and what may be the actual facts of the matter when they come to light.  The question really is whether you can imply souls due to someone being able to read and understand law and I think it a weak link.  It also kind of means that just one gorilla law student gives all gorillas/primates/mammals/vertebrates/animals full 'souls rights'.  Slippery slope kind of stuff.  If you use a soul as a distinction you should actually be sure of how to define it accurately.

Comment: The issue of accurate definition I think would be a problem for all proposals. For example, if we pick "individual rights", "citizen rights", "sentient rights", would these cover androids, like Data of Star Trek?

Comment: Argg, this is my point, if you want to use a word to describe who is eligible the use the word accurately.  Data would not be covered because he has no soul but might be because the law says so.  Obviously it would be optimal if the law followed some rational basis but this is just something that we can hope for.

Comment: This debate reinforces the correctness of Ville Niemi’s answer — no one term serves. It will shift based on the political forces that provide those rights.

Comment: @SRM: Your comment (and Ville's answer) are stating something that is correct, but this question starts from a set definition of who the rights apply to. It's not a question of "should these rights apply to these particular people", it's a question of "what should I name the group of all people who these rights apply to". The latter is a semantical argument, not a political one.

Comment: @Flater and the point is that the question doesn't describe the conditions under which these various species developed the political framework of these rights. Without that, I don't think an answer can be provided that will *necessarily* make sense in whatever story world this goes into (might get lucky but cannot answer with certainty).

Comment: @SRM: As far as I'm aware OP is looking for a name which is self-describing to an English speaking reader. Yes, this fictional world may have created words/names of their own but that's beyond the scope of finding a name that inherently makes sense to a (English speaking) reader.

Answer (score 3):

Sentient rights.

Base sentient rights.

Basic sentient rights.

Universal sentient rights.

Could omit sentient as well.

Basic rights.

Are the general terms, but you could add some politics and worldbuilding to this term and do something like:

Elfvala accord rights.

Basic alliance rights.

Comment: +1 for Universal Sentient Rights

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with **individual rights**.  The whole concept is that there are fundamental freedoms that no one, not even the government or "the majority", can take away from an individual person.  In tyrannies, communist countries, etc, they often pervert the concept of "rights of the people" to mean "powers of the mob" rather than "rights of individuals", and thereby destroy the concept that individuals have rights.  But I don't think it's reasonable that the twisted and false concept of rights is what you want to convey.  The important thing is that rights belong to individuals as individuals, not as a collective.

Comment: Big call that cat-people and lizard-people necessarily live in individualist rather than collectivist societies!

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata Many humans live in collectivist societies; that doesn't mean tyranny and despair are "human rights".  The individual rights I'm talking about exist even when they are infringed upon.  If "rights" just means "the status quo where you are" then the concept of universal individual or "people" rights is an absurdity.

Answer (score 2):

John Scalzi in [Fuzzy Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_Nation) (which is oddly all about this kind of law), called it "Sentient Rights".

If you use that, at least you're not inventing the term. There's prior use you can point to.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Intelligent being rights" ?

KISS

Comment: Can you provide some reasoning behind the proposed name, to flesh your answer out a bit more?

Comment: @L.Dutch: He did. His answer depends solely on writing clearly rather than how the term would have arisen in context.

Comment: You can shorten it to "Beings rights"

Answer (score 1):

You also could pin it to a major religion, which most of your sentient beings follow. Or use the name of the ruler who put the rights into place, or name it after an era or event (all out war, severe flooding, earthquake, uprising etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I like the **Sentient Rights**, **Sapient Rights**, and **Natural Rights** mentioned before. But, personally, I would dive more into the worldbuilding of your universe.

Here and now, humans differentiate themselves from the other living being to the point that only a minority perceive themselves as animals. (For example, everything that is not human is not included in their law system. Although a lot of humans consider pet dogs as close friends, it's those humans that are held responsible for the actions of those animals by the human authorities.)

**Imagine a society build on a broader scope of sentient beings, how would they call themselves?**

Human is a very old word, with a long journey, across time and space. A fast google search shows us that the word could come from Proto-Indo-European. The meaning, '*earthling*' or '*earthly being*', shows the opposition with their gods, who live in the sky. So, if you would be lazy, you could call this community of sentient beings '*humans*', and thus call it **human rights**.

Personally, as a reader, I prefer authors who use a bit more of their brainpower, seeking for original terms through research in facts, imagination, or both (those who I prefer ^_^ ). You could **think of a word** in some (invented) proto-language, that is clearly **defining how an archaic group of sentient beings** were perceiving themselves **and make the word travel throughout the centurie**s and regions evolving with the perception that those beings have of themselves.

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human#Etymology_and_definition
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homo#Latin
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/human
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dhghem-
- https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-etymology-of-the-word-human

Answer (score 1):

**Subject Rights**

In enlightenment philosophy, a [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(philosophy)) is one who acts on the world. Since the whole notion of individual rights came up with enlightenment, a technical philosophical term from that era could stick. To subject literally means to throw under, so there's also a hint at an authority - king, state, what have you that might fit well with your world.

Also, a medieval or early modern world might only start to think in terms of consciousness etc:

> *Subject* as a key-term in thinking about human consciousness began its career with the German Idealists, in response to David Hume's radical skepticism. The idealists' starting point was Hume's conclusion that there is nothing to the self over and above a big, fleeting bundle of perceptions. The next step was to ask how this undifferentiated bundle comes to be experienced as a unity – as a single subject.

I'd only go with the term subject rigths if I wanted an early modern or late medieval feel to my story, I think for other timeframes other terms are a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to simply say "[sapient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom) rights". "Being rights" could also work, but it is a bit too general.

Answer (score 0):

"Human" right might BE the right word, depending how it's used.

In **The Last Starfighter**, the term "human" is a term used by the Star League to refer to sentient/sapient beings of any planet. Grig, Alex Rogan's alien co-pilot is also a human, although he's of a lizard race. When Alex wears his uniform for the first time, Grig says "NOW you look Human!"

Answer (score 0):

## "Rights for Life"

because it's also kind of a word play :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good answers here but @flater has a good point about why we use the term 'human rights' since we don't extend them to anything not human. An option would be to invent a term to encompass all any sentient/sapient being but something that rolls off the tongue. You might even introduce it as a word imported from a language used by a people who have long acknowledged the existence of many sentient species.

I was thinking about how the word Fae is a synonym for fairy, but in many stories there are many types of fairies each with their own specific name and the term Fae or Fairy used as a universal term for all types of Fairies. And then also what might be a word in a Fae language that they used to include all sentient species.